# Created Android virtual device not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I created an AVD in Android Studio but it's not showing when I go to layout->`activity_main.xml`. The error message is showing as below.

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Under the `activity_main.xml` there are two files: `activity_main.xml` and `activity_main.xml`(land). Under Component Tree and Properties space on the right it shows "nothing to show".

When I try to render it, it shows this error message:

Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: action_bar

The xml file looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"    
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"      
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I figured the problem. I change the *Android Version to User when rending layouts in the IDE* from the best pick to version21, which is next to AppTheme and MainActivity, above the display box.

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to happen with Android Studio after one of the recent updates. This answer works for me: just change it to "API 21: Android 5.0.1" and the rendering will work. What's more, you can then switch it back to "API 22: Android 5.1" and the original problem is suddenly gone.